# Flutter Provider: Is it a performance concern to have multiple nested provider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

When using provider, I'm wondering if there are any issues binding multiple levels of the subtree to a parent value.

For example:

```
MainView - Provides Foo
  - SubView1 - binds to foo
   - SubView1_1 - binds to foo
     - LeafNode1 - binds to foo
```

Is this going to cause multiple rebuilds or performance concerns? Should I be instead passing the provided values from SubView1 into SubView1_1 and LeafNode1 
manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no issue with both nesting consumers and nesting providers

It may actually be more optimized, as it allows rebuilding only subsets of the tree

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any performance concern by using it, moreover, we should use consumers if we want to change some specific widget only on screen. This is the best approach I can say in terms of coding practice.

```
 return Container(
    // ...
    child: Consumer<PersonModel>(
      builder: (context, person, child) {
        return Text('Name: ${person.name}');
      },
    ),
  );
```

Like in the above example, we only required to update the value of Single Text Widget so add consumer there instead of Provider which is accessible to others widget as well.